# Adding Earth Engine Raster to Mapbox map

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, mapbox

I have a bunch of data created in Google Earth Engine and I want to add some raster layers to a map created with Mapbox GL JS.

One way I managed to do it is via the Mapbox Studio tileset upload. However, this seems quite complex, download image from EE, process to 8-bit, save as rgb, upload,...

Another answer is [Adding layer made in Google Earth Engine Code Editor to Mapbox](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262182), which suggests to upload it to cloud storage bucket and add it by mapbox-gl using addSource. However, until now I didn't manage to get it running this way.

This example [here](https://observablehq.com/@gena/google-earth-engine-example-02-image-as-a-mapbox-layer) is pretty much what I want to do, unfortunately I don't understand how to use it for my own data.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: It's old&closed, but you can try these:  
https://gist.github.com/wboykinm/8108799  
https://github.com/stamen/sm2/blob/master/sources.json

Comment: Not suer how that helps poetyi.....